# Rowbinding all combinations of two vectors for each variation in a third vector

Tags: r

I have data as follows:

```
cat <- structure(c("east", "north", "south", "west"), .Dim = c(1L, 4L
), .Dimnames = list("categories", NULL))
down <- structure(c(0L, 25L, 50L, 100L, 250L, 500L, 1000L, 1500L, 3000L
), .Dim = c(1L, 9L), .Dimnames = list("lowers", NULL))
up <- structure(c(25L, 50L, 100L, 250L, 500L, 1000L, 1500L, 3000L, 
1000000L), .Dim = c(1L, 9L), .Dimnames = list("uppers", NULL))
```

I would like to combine this data as follows:

```
cat  east north south west east north south west
down    0     0     0    0   25    25    25   25
up     25    25    25   25   50    50    50   50
```

Altough it seems simple, I have no idea where to start..

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you want `out <- rbind(up,down); colnames(out) <- rep(c(cat), length.out = ncol(out))`

Comment: @akrun It comes very close to the first one, but then `east` with each combination of `down` and `up`.

Comment: Can you check the update in the solution.  I guess it needs `rep`lication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps

```
out <- rbind(rep(down, each = length(cat)), rep(up, each = length(cat)))
colnames(out) <- rep(c(cat), length.out = ncol(out))
row.names(out) <- c('down', 'up')
```

-output

```
> out
     east north south west east north south west east north south west east north south west east north south west east north south west east north south west east
down    0     0     0    0   25    25    25   25   50    50    50   50  100   100   100  100  250   250   250  250  500   500   500  500 1000  1000  1000 1000 1500
up     25    25    25   25   50    50    50   50  100   100   100  100  250   250   250  250  500   500   500  500 1000  1000  1000 1000 1500  1500  1500 1500 3000
     north south west    east   north   south    west
down  1500  1500 1500    3000    3000    3000    3000
up    3000  3000 3000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000
```